# How do I make the button color match my code

Tags: php, html, css

CSS :

```
    .float
                    {
                        color: #FFF;
                        position: fixed;
                        width: 50px;
                        height: 50px;
                        bottom: 15px;
                        left: 15px;
                        background-color: #d59a57;
                        border-radius: 50px;
                        text-align: center;
                        padding-top:9px;    
                        z-index: 99;
                    }
```

HTML :

```
<a onclick="playAudio()" type="button" id='un-mute' class='float'><img src='TEMA 3 FIX/images/music-mute.png' width='30px;'></a>
<a onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button" id='mute' class='float'><img src='TEMA 3 FIX/images/music.png' width='30px;'></a>
```

I want just like this :
[image]

But, in fact the result is like this :
[image]

Comment: The simple solution to this would be just replace the image in the circle by onclick event with the help of javascript.
Default would be Mute , once the user clicks play button , change the style of the image inside the circle to a new image of playing and put these in continuous loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether its parent element have any style issue, there is nothing wrong with this style

```css
.float {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  background-color: #d59a57;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="playAudio()" type="button" id='un-mute' class='float'><img width='30px;'></a>
<a onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button" id='mute' class='float'><img width='30px;'></a>
```